# App icon looks awful in iTunes and in App Store

Tags: ios, icons, app-store

I have uploaded my iOS application to App Store. I have provided 1024x1024 transparent icon with the app. However, the app icon looks really awful in iTunes application on my Mac and in App Store.

Below is the illustration for what I am talking about. Leftmost picture is the icon as shown in iOS 6.x, middle one is for iOS 7.x and the rightmost is for iTunes.

Why iTunes displays my icon like this and what can I do about it?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't provide transparent icon file

Comment: can you explain in brief why does this help?

Comment: I think resizing algorithm in itunes just don't correctly make antialiasing

Comment: +1, do you found this by yourself or do you have any reference?

Comment: Just an own experience... may be this may vary depend on file format by the way

Comment: Thank you, it helped. I submitted new build of my app with opaque icon and this fixed the issue.